# Can someone explain what is wrong with my codes?

Tags: python

I want to make a function that return the sum of all the multiple of 3 or 5 that below 1000

```
def trying(number):
box = 0
    while number < 1000:
        if number %3 or %5:
            box = box + number
        number -=1
    return box
```

​

Comment: I don't think Project Euler likes it when you ask Stack Overflow for help.  http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Comment: Please remember to add all the information you can: is there an error? Is the output wrong?

Comment: Also, remember that Python is whitespace sensitive - this code won't work the way it's displayed.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that your code never terminates, since you're counting down (`-=`) and you haven't set a lower bound on the while loop. Probably you want `while number > 0` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` statements require two complete conditions.  It is not like English when you say "Do you want to go in the morning or evening?"  You have to say "Do you want to go IN THE morning or IN THE evening?"  The `%5` does not have anything to reference to.  That would be like saying "Do you want to go evening?" which does not make sense.  With that being said, you must use `if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0:` so that the %5 operator has a value on which to operate.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

use : `if number %3==0 or number %5==0:` as `number %3 or %5` is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Don't we want `== 0` in there?